# JSF - calling a method of the Bean after a <jsp:forward>

Tags: jsf

My first .jsp (index.jsp) does a < jsp:forward page="/pages/homes.faces"> to use the framework JSF.
Now, I need to use a bean to show some informations in the home page but I don't know how to call the method initPage() in my Bean when I do a < jsp:forward>.

Can somebody help me ?

PS: I see "< f:event>" but we don't use a recent library apparently, so.. it doesn't exist :-)

Thanks in advance.

Angy.

Comment: Decide on the framework! With JSF why don't you want to use facelets? Also, it would be good to start with a good tutorial.

Comment: @skuntsel apparently he's using an old library (probably JSF 1.2) and can't change the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AjaxForJSF and send the JS start event to the server. Otherwise you can just use the `@PostConstruct` annotation that gets called if the bean is created.

```
@PostConstruct
public void initPage() {
// init the page..
}
```